# Bash script - how to insert value of variable as new line, 2 line after matching a pattern in text file

Tags: linux, bash

I want to add value of variable as new line, 2 line after matching a pattern. Below is the example.

Below is contents of line before adding value of variable as new line,2 line after matching pattern "FILTER datalist"

```
FILTER datalist

{

"DEBAU00_NFS_fmabackup_BBTFLRBAU01"

}

FILTER copylist

{

}
```

Below is the desired result , in case value of variable is Laptop.

```
FILTER datalist

{

"DEBAU00_NFS_fmabackup_BBTFLRBAU01"

Laptop

}
```

I have tried below.

```
sed '/^FILTER datalist/{N;N;s/$/\Laptop/}' file_name
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? And what is the `pattern`? Be clear about the input, requirement and the expected output.

Comment: @sjsam ,I have edited my question

Comment: Hmm.. But you haven't shown any effort to solve the problem Any effort, though minimal, is expected here..

Comment: I have tried  sed '/^FILTER datalist/{N;N;s/$/\Laptop/}' file_name. But it is not giving me desired result. It is appending "aptop" to a existing line. It  is not adding Laptop as new line. Moreover i need to put value of variable.

Comment: Please put that in question which would make it complete. Please see [mcve]

Comment: Also, if it is `json`, then I suggest using `jq` which is the write tool for the job.

Comment: it is bash script.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem in describing the problem properly.  Initially you had no data between the curly braces. Now, data started appearing all of a sudden in the possible input.

Comment: Apology sjsam for confusion. My objective is to place value of variable after 2 line , after matching a pattern . In case there is already a line, it should not replace that line instead it should place value of variable after second line then existing line should move to next line. Hope i am clear now.

Comment: No worries. I have edited my answer to meet your requirement.. But in future please be specific about the problem `:-)`

Comment: It is giving me message "sed: invalid option -- 'E'"

Comment: Use the `-r` option instead of `-E`, Some systems doesn't support it.

Comment: thanks sjsam. I will try this and let you know. Sorry for late response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sed` with branching to achieve your objective.

```
$ cat casefile48486676
FILTER datalist

{

"DEBAU00_NFS_fmabackup_BBTFLRBAU01"

}

FILTER copylist

{

}
$ variable="Laptop\n\n" #bash variable
$ sed -E "/FILTER datalist/{:l1;/^}$/! {n;bl1};s/(^.*$)/$variable\1/}" casefile48486676
```

**Output**

```
FILTER datalist

{

"DEBAU00_NFS_fmabackup_BBTFLRBAU01"

Laptop

}

FILTER copylist

{

}
```

Comment: Thanks sjsam. I have tried this but it is replacing the existing line instead of adding as new line. Laptop is added as new line but it replace a existing line.My objective is to add Laptop as new line.

Comment: @HiteshKataria : See the edit, but I am not a big fan of hard-coding newlines anyways. :/

Comment: I have edited the question with result. Still having trouble.

Comment: @HiteshKataria If the output fits your requirements , see [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).